# Way to pivot multiple rows into columns in Tableau using Custom SQL?

Tags: pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, tableau-desktop

I am using a snowflake data source for tableau and unfortunately the generated results show like this

| Agent | Manager | Row | Question | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Cindy | 1 | Breakfast? | yes |
| Bob | Cindy | 2 | Lunch? | no |
| Bob | Cindy | 3 | Dinner? | maybe |
| Jim | Debby | 1 | Breakfast? | yes |
| Jim | Debby | 2 | Lunch? | no |
| Jim | Debby | 3 | Dinner? | maybe |

and I'm trying to get it to look like this

| Agent | Manager | Question1 | question2 | question3 | answer1 | answer2 | answer3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Cindy | Breakfast? | Lunch? | Dinner? | yes | no | maybe |
| Jim | Debby | Breakfast? | Lunch? | Dinner? | yes | no | maybe |

The pivot options aren't available because it's coming from snowflake, and I only seem to find results that show how to convert columns to rows using SQL, but nothing showing how to do rows to columns in Tableau from a snowflake connection.  There seems to be certain things you can't use in the tableau sql that you can do in snowflake so I'm just at a loss at this point.

The snowflake data is also unavailable to do queries on so I'm stuck only able to fix it through Tableau. Any suggestions on how to do this? or if it's doable? Thanks in advance.